# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAccounts' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, iife

I'm following John Papa's Angular Style guide for creating a small application, and I can't seem to work out an issue with the `controller` using a method from a `service`...

**module**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var accountsApp = angular.module('accountsApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate']);
})();
```

**Controller**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('accountsApp')
        .controller('accountsCtrl', accountsCtrl);

    accountsCtrl.$inject = ['$log'];

    function accountsCtrl($log, accountsDataSvc) {
        /* jshint validthis:true */
        var vm = this;
        vm.title = 'Accounts';
        vm.accounts = [];
        vm.accountForm = null;
        vm.account = { id: 0, name: '', description: '' }

        activate();

        function activate() {
            return getAccounts(1).then(function() {
                $log.info('Accounts loaded');
            });
        }

        function getAccounts(id) {
            return accountsDataSvc.getAccounts(id).then(function(data) { //error here
                vm.accounts = data;
                return vm.accounts;
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

**Service**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('accountsApp')
        .factory('accountsDataSvc', accountsDataSvc);

    accountsDataSvc.$inject = ['$http', '$log'];

    function accountsDataSvc($http, $log, $q) {

        var uri = '***';

        var service = {
            getAccounts: accounts
        };

        return service;

        //////////////////////

        function accounts(userId) {
            $log.info(uri + userId + ' called');
            return $http.get(uri + userId)
                .then(getAccountsComplete)
                .catch(function (message) {
                    $log.error('XHR Failed for getAccounts ' + message);
                });

            function getAccountsComplete(data, status, headers, config) {
                return data.data[0].data.results;
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

When I run the application, I get the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAccounts' of undefined** within the controller, but I can't see where I have gone wrong - any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to inject accountsDataSvc into your controller

Try:

```
accountsCtrl.$inject = ['$log', 'accountsDataSvc'];
```

Comment: Matt, thanks for that - I thought I only needed to inject the Angular specific dependencies here, Angular newb error - I will accept when SO lets me.

Comment: I'm a newb as well. Whenever an error like that pops up I check two things: 1) Dependency Injection, did I tell my controller about all services it depends on; 2) My index.html file, am I referencing all necessary .js files.